# unable to supply app service plan id as variable to the terraform module

Tags: terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

i am trying to create appservices through module, in root module, i am calling appservice plan child module to get appservice plan id. but unfortunately i am getting the following error.

**Error: Invalid variable name
│
│   on ../../modules/appservice/variable.tf line 17, in variable "var.app_service_plan":
│   17: variable "var.app_service_plan" {
│
│ A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters, digits, underscores, and dashes.**

here is my code

```
   appservice module: 

   appservice.tf:
   resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice" {
   for_each = var.appservicename
   name                = each.value.appservices
   location            = var.appservice_location
   resource_group_name = var.appservice_resourcegroup
   app_service_plan_id = var.app_service_plan


   }
  variable.tf:

  variable "appservices" {
    type = map(object({
    appservicename = string
   }))
   }
  variable "appservice_location" {
    type = string
   }
  variable "appservice_resourcegroup" {
   type = string
  }

  variable "var.app_service_plan" {
   type = string
  }

  root module:

  main.tf:

  terraform {
    required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=2.68.0"
    }}} 

  provider "azurerm" {
    features {
    }}

  module "resourcegroup" {
    source = "../../modules/resourcegroup/"
    rg_name = "terraarmrg1234"
    rg_location = "South India"
    }

  module "Vnet" {
     source = "../../modules/Vnet/"
     vnet_name = "terravnet1"
     vnet_address_space = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
     subnet1_name = "terravnet1subnet1"
     address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
     }

    module "asp" {
      source = "../../modules/asp"
      plan_count = "2"
      aspname = "azterrasp1"
        }

    module "appservice" {
      source = "../../modules/appservice"
      appservices = {
        "appservice1" = {
            appservicename  = "appservice1"},
        "appservice2" = {
            appservicename = "appservice2"}}
      appservice_location = module.resourcegroup.rg.location
      appservice_resourcegroup = module.resourcegroup.rg.name
      app_service_plan   = module.asp[0].asp.id  }
```

could some one help me if i am missing something .. thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, what exactly is your `app_service_plan`?

Comment: Hi Marcin,  here it is app_service_plan   = module.asp[0].asp.id

Comment: What exactly is `module.asp[0].asp.id`? Sadly your question lacks details.

Comment: actually i have created appservice plans using count , i am reffering here one of them, this is how it looks in state file
"module": "module.asp[0]",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "azurerm_app_service_plan",
      "name": "asp",
      
      "instances": [
        {
          "index_key": 0,
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "app_service_environment_id": "",
            "id": "/subscriptions/a8e2fc5d-80b4-420b-984f-1540b4f0fedf/resourceGroups/terraazure1234/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/azterrasp1-0",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the name of your variable that is wrong:

```
variable "var.app_service_plan" {
```

Should probably be:

```
variable "app_service_plan" {
```

as you do not prefix your variable names in the definitions with `var.`